# Is there a formula or an algorithm to find the power of any integer that returns zero?

Tags: exponentiation

Is there a formula or algorithm that can find the power ${^x}$ that returns $0$ for $n$ ${\mathbb N} $?

Comment: Do you have *any* example of a power of an integer that returns zero?

Comment: Only by trial and error I can return an approximate such that $2$ to the power $-13.287$ is $0.00010049$.  I know that $0$ to the power of any number is also $0$.  I am looking for the approach to solve this question?

Comment: $[n^x=0]\implies[n=0]\wedge[x\neq0]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such thing exists.
Taking the example of $n = 2$, then $f(x) = 2^{-x}$ is a strictly decreasing function on $(0, \infty)$.
You can see:
$f(1) = \frac{1}{2}$, $f(2) = \frac{1}{4}$ etc etc, but only:
$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

No number, other than zero itself, has a solution to what you want. What I mean is that $n^x \neq 0$ unless $n = 0$. What you can do is just raising it to a very large negative power, e.g. with your example $2^{-13}\approx 0$, but $2^{-100}$ is even closer to zero, and $2^{-1000}$ is even closer etc. This is true for any $n > 0$.